# Adding XML nodes to an existing XML using XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a requirement to add new XML nodes to an existing XML using XPATH.

Existing XML:

```
<create>
   <article>
      <identifier>Test</identifier>
   </article>
</create>
```

XSLT Used (Got if from another thread in stackoverflow):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vPop" as="element()*">
    <item path="/create/article[1]/id">1</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/description">bar</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/name[1]">foo</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/price[1]/amount">00.00</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/price[1]/currency">USD</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/price[2]/amount">11.11</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/price[2]/currency">AUD</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/id">2</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/description">some name</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/name[1]">some description</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/price[1]/amount">00.01</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/price[1]/currency">USD</item>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="my:subTree($vPop/@path/concat(.,'/',string(..)))"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:subTree" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="pPaths" as="xs:string*"/>

  <xsl:for-each-group select="$pPaths"
    group-adjacent=
        "substring-before(substring-after(concat(., '/'), '/'), '/')">
    <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key()">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test=
          "substring-after(current-group()[1], current-grouping-key())">
         <xsl:element name=
           "{substring-before(concat(current-grouping-key(), '['), '[')}">

          <xsl:sequence select=
            "my:subTree(for $s in current-group()
                         return
                            concat('/',substring-after(substring($s, 2),'/'))
                             )
            "/>
        </xsl:element>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using above XSLT the XPATHs are converted to XML nodes. But the issue is existing XML nodes (`<identifier>Test</identifier>`) are lost. Kindly help to fix this issue. This is a sample XML and the actual XML contains many existing XML nodes.

Actual results:

```
<create>
   <article>
      <id>1</id>
      <description>bar</description>
      <name>foo</name>
      <price>
         <amount>00.00</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </price>
      <price>
         <amount>11.11</amount>
         <currency>AUD</currency>
      </price>
   </article>
   <article>
      <id>2</id>
      <description>some name</description>
      <name>some description</name>
      <price>
         <amount>00.01</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </price>
   </article>
</create>
```

Expected result:

```
<create>
   <article>
      <identifier>Test</identifier>
      <id>1</id>
      <description>bar</description>
      <name>foo</name>
      <price>
         <amount>00.00</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </price>
      <price>
         <amount>11.11</amount>
         <currency>AUD</currency>
      </price>
   </article>
   <article>
      <id>2</id>
      <description>some name</description>
      <name>some description</name>
      <price>
         <amount>00.01</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </price>
   </article>
</create>
```

Comment: Creating elements *from* XPath is a weird (and fundamentally broken) way to generate XML. What's the point of doing that? Who writes the XPaths you're using to generate the XML?

Comment: And what would be the rules for deciding which value to form if the main input has e.g. an element `/create/article[1]/id` and your variable with XPaths wants to add it also?

Comment: @Tomalak Ideally the requirement is to add new fields to a document dynamically. During development time the developers are not aware of these fields. Hence we will be storing those fields as XPATH in cache. During run time we will create an XML based out for that document and then create these new fields from the XPATH stored in cache.

Comment: @MartinHonnen If the same element already exist in main input then the variable from XPATH can override it.

Comment: Again. That's a fundamentally broken design. It's not clever, it's not necessary, it's not extensible, it's not sustainable - it's not a good idea. You really should re-work this part. If you can write XPath to "store" structural information about XML, you can just as well write XML directly.

Comment: In the end it sounds as if you want a two step transformation, the first step is the one you have where you create new nodes from your paths, in the second step you need to merge the input document with the newly created nodes.

Comment: @Tomalak The requirement for adding fields dynamically is for a short period of time till we make the changes and deploy. During the period of development and deploying these new fields we need our services to support these newly added fields.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes that is correct.

Comment: There is a merge algorithm http://web.archive.org/web/20160502194427/http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt.html done in XSLT, in XSLT 3 yould chain it to your other transformation using `fn:transform`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you. Let me have a look at it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen It would have been better if we could achieve the result in single XLST. The given XSLT can create XML node out of XPATHs but will remove the existing XML nodes.

Comment: Well, you can do it in a single XSLT but an exact merge algorithm is complex and you haven't shown yours or specified yours, not even shown the result you expect.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have updated the thread with actual and expected outcomes. XML nodes from XPATH will always have precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rough outline of the create the new nodes based on your existing function and merge them with the input document approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns:my="http://example.com/my-functions"
  expand-text="yes">
  
<xsl:variable name="vPop" as="element()*">
    <item path="/create/article[1]/id">1</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/description">bar</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/name[1]">foo</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/price[1]/amount">00.00</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/price[1]/currency">USD</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/price[2]/amount">11.11</item>
    <item path="/create/article[1]/price[2]/currency">AUD</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/id">2</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/description">some name</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/name[1]">some description</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/price[1]/amount">00.01</item>
    <item path="/create/article[2]/price[1]/currency">USD</item>
 </xsl:variable>
 
 <xsl:variable name="new-nodes">
   <xsl:sequence select="my:subTree($vPop/@path/concat(.,'/',string(..)))"/>
 </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:sequence select="my:merge(*, $new-nodes/*)"/>
  </xsl:template>


 <xsl:function name="my:merge" as="node()*">
   <xsl:param name="node1" as="node()*"/>
   <xsl:param name="node2" as="node()*"/>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="$node1, $node2" group-by="path()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:sequence select="my:merge(@*, current-group()[2]/@*)"/>
       <xsl:sequence select="my:merge(node(), current-group()[2]/node())"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:function name="my:subTree" as="node()*">
   
   
  <xsl:param name="pPaths" as="xs:string*"/>

  <xsl:for-each-group select="$pPaths"
    group-adjacent=
        "substring-before(substring-after(concat(., '/'), '/'), '/')">
    <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key()">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test=
          "substring-after(current-group()[1], current-grouping-key())">
         <xsl:element name=
           "{substring-before(concat(current-grouping-key(), '['), '[')}">

          <xsl:sequence select=
            "my:subTree(for $s in current-group()
                         return
                            concat('/',substring-after(substring($s, 2),'/'))
                             )
            "/>
        </xsl:element>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But most merging requirements are way more complex than that simple `my:merge` I have shown there, so you would need to refine that function.

Comment: This works fine, generating new XML nodes out of XPATH and merging with initial XML, but the XML tag values are not showing up. Could you please help to fix it<create>
   <article>
      <identifier>Test</identifier>
      <id/>
      <description/>
      <name/>
      <price>
         <amount/>
         <currency/>
      </price>
      <price>
         <amount/>
         <currency/>
      </price>
   </article>
   <article>
      <id/>
      <description/>
      <name/>
      <price>
         <amount/>
         <currency/>
      </price>
   </article>
</create>

Comment: I do get content at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jy6KM7B