# How to add an element specified in a variable at a xpath location specified in param in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to add an xml element to a specified location within xml document.
The problem is, that element will be in a param and also location (which is xpath) is also specified in param of xslt stylesheet.

XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body>
  <m:GetPriceResponse xmlns:m="https://www.w3schools.com/prices">
    <m:Price>1.90</m:Price>
  </m:GetPriceResponse>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

XPATH =/soap:Envelop/soap:Body

variable having xml element to add = `<customer>foo</customer>`
(this xml element to be added is getting added from external configuration to a parameter and I am using saxon:parse(param_name) to store it in a variable.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70605840/adding-xml-nodes-to-an-existing-xml-using-xpath

Comment: @MartinHonnen can you please give a small snippet for this specific problem?

Comment: You haven't given a specific problem, I am afraid,  it is not clear how your input and how your parameters look, whether you have an XPath that "fits" into an already existing tree structure (i.e. you just need to add a leaf child or text node or an attribute) or whether you might need to create all the ancestors of the elements given in the path. It is also not clear how complex the path parameter can be. So at least spell out your requirements in some detail with some examples and explain why the existing solutions don't help for your case.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Actually I am very new to XSLT so I it is difficult to understand your answer in the link you gave. Edited the question. Hope it clarifies my problem. Thank you.

Comment: So you have that XML input and the two parameters, but which is the corresponding output you want to create? And as you mention `saxon:parse`, which edition and version of Saxon exactly do you use or can you use?

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Saxon then you could leverage the [`saxon:eval()`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/functions/saxon/eval.html) function to evaluate the XPath from the `$path` parameter.

Below is an example that evaluates the XPath with the result in a variable, and uses it in a template match pattern to test whether `generate-id()` of the `$eval` is equal to that of the matched element. If it matches, then it will add the `$add` parameter as XML using [`parse-xml()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml), as a child of that element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.1"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/">
   
  <xsl:param name="path" select="'/soap:Envelope/soap:Body'"/>
  <xsl:param name="add" select="'&lt;customer>foo&lt;/customer>'"/>
    
  <xsl:variable name="eval" select="saxon:eval(saxon:expression($path))" as="item()*"/>
       
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
    
  <xsl:template match="*[. is $eval]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:sequence select="@*, parse-xml($add), node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>      
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `version="3.1"` but use of `generate-id`? You could just use `*[. is $eval]` instead of `*[generate-id() eq generate-id($eval)]`, no?

Comment: good suggestion! I've updated the answer.